# How to do this sql with pure activerecord (rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't figure out how to manage this purely with active record.  I understand it doesn't handle outer joins...

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN responses 
ON people.id = responses.person_id 
WHERE responses.person_id is NULL;
```

MODELS:

```
Person
id
has_many :responses

Response
id
belongs_to :person
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
named_scope :without_responses, :include    => :responses, 
                                :conditions => "responses.id IS NULL"
```

Comment: :without_responses is probably a better name ;)

Comment: Wow.  My life has truly been enriched and I now have much, much more faith in activerecord.  Thanks for this!!